# How to create Gallery in asp.net code behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to create a Gallery of data from server in asp.net under vb, each Gallery item should look like the following snapshot 
[image]

and it should looks like the following snapshot 
[image]

please help or guide me.
Kind Regards,

Comment: Did you try something already? Did you encounter some specific issues with your code that you would like to ask about? How can we help you?

Comment: I don't know how to do it, and is it doable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Solution:

Use a List View, or a repeater to create the Gallery items, then use Jquery to animate them.

Second Solution: Try to search for a ready made asp.net image gallery, for example check :
[Creating an Image Grid (Photo Gallery) with ASP.NET using ListView Controlr](http://geekswithblogs.net/omtalsania7/archive/2012/12/27/how-to-create-an-image-grid-with-asp.net-44.5-using.aspx)

Comment: Manythanks, can you mention a link or example on web for the first approach, or if you have your own example

Comment: For the Jquery animation, check http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/jquery-image-galleries-sliders-best-of/, and for the asp.net code, you can use the example shown in the "Second Solution"